# Arc around a node in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,auto]
        \node (A) {$Q(\sqrt[6]{2}\:)$};
        \node (B) [below of=A]{$Q(\sqrt{2}\:)$};
        \node (C) [below of=B] {$Q$};
        \draw[-] (A) to node {3; $x^3-2=Irr(\sqrt[6]{2},Q(\sqrt{2},x)$} (B);
        \draw[-] (B) to node {2; $x^2-2=Irr(\sqrt{2},Q,x)$} (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

I am wanting an arc (or whatever term should be used) from node A to node C without passing through node B; however, all of my attempts have been futile.

The third line that I've been drawing is a straight line from node A to node C; how can I change it so that it instead curves around node B, preferably to the left?

Comment: Hi Clayton, welcome to the site! Please make sure that the code you post is compilable by others, by adding the minimal required preamble (starting from `\documentclass`) and any macro definitions that are necessary. In this case, for example, the `\Q` is undefined, but you could actually take it out of the code completely, because it is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: No problem. You can make a block of code by indenting each line 4 spaces or by highlighting everything and clicking on the `{}` button in the question editor. Also, as @Jake points out, you should make sure that we can compile the code by just copying and pasting it into our own editors. This is called a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Can you update the code so we can compile it?

Comment: @Jake: I've updated the code (and removed the line that I don't want anyway).

Comment: @Adam: I have updated the code, as requested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can draw a curved line using `\draw (A) to [bend right=40] (C);`, where the optional argument to `bend right` controls the curvature:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,auto]
        \node (A) {$Q(\sqrt[6]{2}\:)$};
        \node (B) [below of=A]{$Q(\sqrt{2}\:)$};
        \node (C) [below of=B] {$Q$};
        \draw[-] (A) to node {3; $x^3-2=Irr(\sqrt[6]{2},Q(\sqrt{2},x)$} (B);
        \draw[-] (B) to node {2; $x^2-2=Irr(\sqrt{2},Q,x)$} (C);
        \draw (A) to [bend right=45] node [left] {text} (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I may ask; what is the 40 representative of?

Comment: @Clayton: It's the angle by which the start/end differs from the straight line: `bend right=0` would be a straight line, `bend right=90` means the initial and final directions of the curve are 90 degrees from the straight line. You can additionally control the curvature of the arc using `looseness=<value>`. A looseness of `2` will make the arc wider, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution is to use `controls`, which basically allows you to control the direction that the line 'leaves' the first node at and the direction at which it 'enters' the second node:

**Update**: You can also add text to the line created by the `\draw` by placing a node after it, before closing it with `;`. See [How to label a line created with draw command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50815/how-to-label-a-line-created-with-draw-command) for the details of how this works.

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,auto]
        \node (A) {$Q(\sqrt[6]{2}\:)$};
        \node (B) [below of=A]{$Q(\sqrt{2}\:)$};
        \node (C) [below of=B] {$Q$};
        \node (D) [below of=C] {};
        \draw[-] (A) to node {3; $x^3-2=Irr(\sqrt[6]{2},Q(\sqrt{2},x)$} (B);
        \draw[-] (B) to node {2; $x^2-2=Irr(\sqrt{2},Q,x)$} (C);
        \draw[-] (A)..controls +(west:2) and +(west:2)..(C) node [left,pos=0.5] {text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is fantastic! I didn't know there could be so much control over the diagrams :) Thank you, Adam!

Comment: In your code, I think I understand most of it, but what is the ':2' indicating here? I see that the controls is the command you want to force the entering/exiting part of the line, the west says precisely which part of the node, but what is the 2?

Comment: How can I label the arc in this case, as I've done with the two lines? I'm currently running trial and error cases...

Comment: @Clayton It's representative of a length, so anything that indicates length in `(La)TeX` can be used here (`cm`, `mm`, `em`, `in`, etc.). The default is `cm`, I believe. So it takes a point 2 centimeters west and sets it as the control point.

Comment: Then, according the [TikZ-PGF manual](http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf): "Suppose you are at point x and the first control point is y. Then the curve will start going in the direction of y at x, that is, the tangent of the curve at x will point toward y." So, the tangent of the curve at the node points toward the control point, which is 2cm to the west.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to label the arc? A quick look in the manual hasn't proven useful yet...

Comment: @Clayton See [How to label a line created with draw command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50815/how-to-label-a-line-created-with-draw-command). I'll update my answer in a second.